# Python: how lexical analyser convert tabs to spaces

Tags: python

In [Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html), it said

> "First, tabs are replaced (from left to right) by one to eight spaces such that the total number of characters up to and including the replacement is a multiple of eight (this is intended to be the same rule as used by Unix)."

I am wondering how this works. For example, when there is multiple tabs, how does the analyser know how to convert each tab?

Comment: 1 tab -> 8 spaces, 2 tabs -> 16 spaces, 3 tabs -> 24 spaces , ... Where is the problem?

Comment: @Matthias It's not that simple. Suppose a line starts with 2 spaces and a tab; the tab might only be replaced by 6 spaces.

Comment: You might find it worthwhile to investigate Python's source code -- the `tok_get` function inside [tokenizer.c](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Parser/tokenizer.c) appears to be responsible for lexing and handling indentation. (It also appears to be responsible for lexing _every_ token, so it's a bit confusing to read)